# Does the warp drive theorically allows travels between other universes?

Tags: multiverse, warp-drives

Does the warp drive allow to travel between universes? Even in a level 2 [multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse)?

Comment: First build your warp drive ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Level 1 multiverses almost certainly exist, and any FTL drive would be able to move between them. As far as i know this includes an Alcubierre drive, assuming you could build one. So yes, an Alcuierre drive could move between level 1 universes.

As far as I know the only even remotely plausible realisation of a level 2 multiverse comes from eternal inflation. Your problem here is that the spacetime in between separate universes is expanding exponentially. I don't know what the top speed of an Alcubierre drive is (I assume there must be a top speed) but I'd be surprised if it was high enough to overcome exponential expansion. So I would judge that no, you can't travel between different level 2 universes.

Comment: satisfying answer, i was thinking the same..thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you cannot go with an Alcubierre drive somewhere where you were not "forecasted" by the builder of the bubble. ["does not mean that Alcubierre bubbles, if it were possible to create them, could not be used as a means of superluminal travel. It only means that the actions required to change the metric and create the bubble must be taken beforehand by some observer whose forward light cone contains the entire trajectory of the bubble."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) Travelling even in level I multiverse can be hard.