# Is it possible to travel between worlds in the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In the [Many Worlds Interpretation (MWI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretatio) of quantum mechanics, all possible outcomes of a measurement occur, and each possible outcome corresponds to a distinct "world" or universe.

Is it possible to travel to between these worlds?

Comment: There are no *"parallel universes of quantum physics"*.

Comment: If you are referring to the many-worlds interpretation of QM, two different points of view exist. Traditional many-worlds interpretation (which ascends to Everett's original work) forbids such travels. However some contemporary authors suggest it might be in some sense possible. But the question remains metaphysical and therefore it is pure speculation.

Comment: Yes such "travel" is possible. Just jump at some solid thing (eg a wall) head first, but miss. You have to practice a lot. When You get "over there" report my best wishes to the late Douglas Adams.

Comment: i think this could be easily rewritten into a reasonable question.

Comment: It's clear as day what he's asking. You just don't like the question.

Comment: I would guess that an attempt to travel between "worlds" would result in the creation of even more "worlds", spiraling (even more) out of control.  (I've long figured that the only way the "many worlds" scheme could work would be if there were some sort of "garbage collection" that somehow coalesced "worlds" which were within a "small delta" of each other.

Comment: Branching of the worlds is associated with experiment. Experiment is an irreversible process, which increases entropy. In many-worlds interpretation, the branching happens, when on the order of $kT$ energy dissipates (corresponds to ~1 bit of measured information, thus the worlds can now be distinguished). However, entropy can also decrease (on the order of few bits) if you're lucky enough, and this corresponds to the merging of already branched worlds. So, in some sense, the answer is yes, though the travelling is somewhat fundamentally uncontrollable.

Comment: It seems that this is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/, so I see no reason to re-open it (even if closed for a "wrong" reason).